# How to split a String by using two identifiers at the same time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a string which i want to split into sub strings either by symbol  **'\n' or '\r'**  , for single identifier splitting we can use

```
string[] strsplit = str.Split('\n') ;
```

but in my case it is not sure weather it is **'\n' or '\r'** ..

can any one please tell me is there is any way to split string like the below mentioned way..

```
string[] strsplit = str.Split('\n' || '\r') ;
```

thanks in Advance and sorry for my Bad english

Comment: is your string formatted with verbatim(@) or not?,because if it is it will not work with the split with that formatt.

Comment: @terrybozzio The verbatim string syntax relates only to how you write the C# string in your code, and has nothing to do with the actual value of the string. The string itself is just a string.

Comment: lol yes i know,then please just for fun try with the split with char params to split this verbatim string @"something\nandmoresomething" the way presented .split(new char[]{'\n});,because i just mention this case,please try and tell me the result.I dont know what op is trying or where the string came from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the case where sometimes you have lines split with sometimes `\n`, sometimes `\r` and sometimes `\r\n` you can do the following

```
someString.Split(new[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

---

Another option is if you want explicitly to include `Environment.NewLine` (`\r\n`) is

```
someString.Split(new[] { "\n", "\r", Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Notice these are now strings (using `"` instead of `'`).

You can change the line skip behavior by changing the `StringSplitOptions` to `StringSplitOptions.None`

Comment: below mentioned case i want to implement can you please suggest me how to implement.. string[] strsplit =str.Split(string[]{ "\n","\r\r\r\r\r\r","\r\r\r\r\r","\r\r\r"}); –

Comment: What you have written is **nearly** there. The `string` array override of `Split` requires both `string[]` *and* `StringSplitOptions`. Additionally you can't define an array like `string[]` you either need to do `new string[]` or the shorter `new[]` which I opted for. Give it a go and message back if you get stuck.

Answer (score 5):

`Split` method has overload which accepts array of `char`:

```
string[] strsplit = str.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }) ;
```

As mentioned in comments you can now do it this way:

```
string[] strsplit = str.Split('\n', '\r') ;
```

Comment: This method has added `params` in C#2.0, so you do not need `char[]` any longer: `str.Split('\n', '\r')`

Comment: Or simply `string[] strsplit = str.Split('\n', '\r');`

Comment: The URL for the MSDN page for the [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

Comment: if suppose there is a case where i need to give identifier like this '\n\r\r\n'  , will it be possible to give

Comment: Yes, but then you will need to use different overload (the one with `string`s not `char`s). In your case it will be `string.Split(string[], StringSplitOptions)`. AdamPorad has posted link above, be sure to check it out.

Comment: @walkhard below mentioned case i want to implement can you please suggest me how to implement..
string[] strsplit =str.Split(string[]{ "\n","\r\r\r\r\r\r","\r\r\r\r\r","\r\r\r"});

Comment: `str.Split(new string[]{ "\n","\r\r\r\r\r\r","\r\r\r\r\r","\r\r\r"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` (this will remove empty entries). Like I wrote earlier, take a look at the documentation page (url posted above)

Answer (score 0):

You say you only want to split by either `\r` or `\n`, but in reality usually people want to also consider `\r\n`, since that's the default Windows line break. If you also want that, you'll need to do a little extra work. One way is to use `StringReader` and let it to the work for you:

```
var lines = new List<string>();
using (var sr = new StringReader(str)) {
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
        lines.Add(line);
    }
}
string[] strsplit = lines.ToArray();
```

This has slightly different behavior than dav_i's answer, when it comes to handling multiple empty lines. Just depends on what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass an array of chars to the Split method

```
string[] arr = "Test\rTest\nTest".Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' });
```